# Java - Returning a new array containing the squares of the elements of its array parameter

Tags: java, arrays

Below I have got a code that returns a new array containing the squares of the elements of its array parameter (the input array should remain unchanged). For instance, if the input array is {0,1,2,3} then the output is then {0,1,4,9}.

```
public static double[] square (double a[]){
    double[] s = new double[a.length];
    for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        s[i]=a[i]*a[i];
    }
    return s;
}
```

Whenever I want to test above code, I have got following problem, I have done a screen shot and the picture is here:
[image: Screenshot]

Any suggestions how I can test the numbers 0,1,2 and 3 ?

Okay as I have mentioned above, I have got a code (above) and I want to:

A) Test it using 0,1,2 and 3.
B) Sadly I had a problem and I couldn't test the numbers. So as an example and describe my problem I did a screenshot. Is my problem clear for everyone now?

Comment: It doesn't look like your posted method is throwing that exception.  In order to help you I'm going to need a stacktrace.

Comment: @jgitter, what's a stacktrace? How can I provide it, so you can help me?

Comment: The code you have shared is fine. The problem is likely related to the way you're using the method. For example, if the parameter `a` is null, the method will fail when you do `a.length`

Comment: upload your screenshot here..it also happen that link you provide will be removed from third party server..

Comment: @Acemi: May not need one.. see my answer below.

Comment: Your problem seems to be with this "BlueJ" thing. Just make a `main` method (or even better, a unit test) to invoke and test your method. Or else change the tags to "BlueJ" because that's where your problem is, it's not in your Java or in arrays.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, I opened up a new thread about it +++> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23345104/bluej-java-code?noredirect=1#comment35750896_23345104

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I see that you're using BlueJ.  I'm not familiar with that IDE, but I believe the error you're seeing: "error: <identifier> expected" is thrown for a failed compile.  That usually shows up for syntactical errors like forgetting a semicolon or curly brace.

-- EDIT --

Example using JUnit4 in case you decide to go that route:

```
@Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
public void testNull() {
    Square.square(null);
}

@Test
public void testArray() {
    double[] squares = Square.square(new double[] {0d, 1d, 2d, 3d});
    Assert.assertEquals(squares[0] == 0d);
    Assert.assertEquals(squares[1] == 1d);
    Assert.assertEquals(squares[2] == 4d);
    Assert.assertEquals(squares[3] == 9d);
}
```

Comment: You're using an IDE, are you sure it isn't compiling on-demand?  I don't mean to be glib, but if you don't know what a stack trace is, you're clearly pretty new to java.

Comment: okay, I simply want to test this code using 0,1,2 and 3, how do I do it?

Comment: I don't know anything about BlueJ.  I would use JUnit.

Comment: okay, is there a way I can compile and check codes online? like jsfiddle for javascript? something similar for java?

Comment: I don't believe there is a Java fiddle.  See my update for an example of how to use junit.

Comment: Also, again, you may just be using BlueJ incorrectly.  I know nothing about BlueJ.

Comment: @Acemi here is an online example: https://ideone.com/HZU76K