# BlueJ - Java Code

Tags: java

I have got following code:

```
public class Square {
    public static double[] square (double a[]){
        double[] s = new double[a.length];
        for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            s[i]=a[i]*a[i];
        }
        return s;
    }
    //other methods...
}
```

And whenever I BlueJ Method call and choose `double[] square (double a[])` and type 0,1,2 and 3, I am keep getting an error message error identifier expected. So I cannot test my numbers, how can I get rid of this problem? Normal if you type 0,1,2 and 3, you supposed to get the square of each number, but for some reason I am not managing it.

EDIT:

This is how I'm trying to test the method:

```
Square.square(0, 1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Post how you're trying to test this code.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza , here is the screenshot: http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o756/deli0102/IT/java_bluej_error_28_apr_2014_zps903ce777.png

Comment: your code is not modularized... the squaring part can be separated from the projection part

Comment: @SargeBorsch what do you mean by your comment? Could you provide more info?

Comment: @Sarge Borsch, do you mean main method is missing?

Comment: @Acemi No, I'm talking about decoupling one task from another.

Comment: @SargeBorsch and how could you decouple it? By adding a new `double square(double)` method?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza see this code http://ideone.com/SFo9As — here, the iteration part is separated and can be reused. Although the types are not so flexible, because Java type system is too primitive. The latter can be mitigated by writing in Scala instead.

Comment: @SargeBorsch that looks good for a more complex scenario. If you have a simple scenario, keep the solution the most simple you can. Note that you could even add usage of threads to enhance the performance of the code (but that would be a little overkill for this very simple example).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza threads don't always improve performance, most of the times they hurt it. But separation of tasks is almost always good. :P

Comment: @SargeBorsch I think you're trying to look like a *I know how to make this stuff better* guy, and that's not the purpose of this site. Good to know there are other ways to solve this problem, though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51612/discussion-between-sarge-borsch-and-luiggi-mendoza)

Comment: @Guys, I am an absolute beginner therefore I always seek for something simple, therefore I really liked LuiggiMendoza solutions & comments. Sarge Borsch thanks for the comments, but for a absolute beginner like myself, I really prefer easy stuff firstly.

Comment: @Acemi that's what I'm trying to say all this time :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you need to send a `double[]` but you're sending 4 `int` arguments. There are two ways to solve this:

1. Send a real `double[]`:

   ```
   Square.square(new double[] { 0, 1, 2, 3} );
   ```
2. Change the method to receive varargs:

   ```
   public static double[] square (double ... a)
   ```

   And now you can pass any amount of arguments:

   ```
   Square.square(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... );
   ```

Just remember to store the result of your method in another `double[]` to evaluate the results:

```
double[] results = Square.square( <add the arguments depending on the chosen solution> );
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(results));
```

---

To test if your code works, you can simply write a `public static void main` method and call the desired method to see if it can be executed, and probably evaluate the results. You can even do this inside `Square` class:

```
public class Square {
    public static double[] square(double[] a) {
        //the definition of your method...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //calling the method to seek if compiles
        double[] results = Square.square(new double[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 });
        //printing the results
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(results));
    }
}
```

If you want/need to **test** the code, this means, execute it and evaluate if you're getting the desired results, you can write a unit test using [JUnit](http://junit.org/). I will just add an example of how the test would look like:

```
public class SquareTest {
    @Test
    public void testSquare {
        double[] expectedResults = { 0, 1, 4, 9 };
        double[] results = Square.square(new double[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 });
        Assert.assertArrayEquals("Not the desired results.", expectedResults, results, 0.00001);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, the code I have given is actually the complete answer of a test and the original question is this: Implement a method public static double [] square (double[]a)that returns a new array containing the squares of the elements of its array parameter (the input array should remain unchanged). For instance, if the input array is {0,1,2,3} then the output is then {0,1,4,9}.

Comment: And I wanted to test this code and then change a bit and test again in order to understand whether I understood everything correctly.

Comment: @Acemi and my answer covers the scenario. Looks like you need to apply the 1st option to test your method.

Comment: okay where should I put this line in my code ==> Square.square(new double[] { 0, 1, 2, 3} ); ? At the moment my code looks like this==> public class Square {
    public static double[] square (double a[]){
        double[] s = new double[a.length];
        for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
            s[i]=a[i]*a[i];
        }
        return s;
    }
    //other methods...
}

Comment: thank you very much I have used this code => public class Square {
    public static double[] square(double[] a) {
        //the definition of your method...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //calling the method to seek if compiles
        double[] results = Square.square(new double[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 });
        //printing the results
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(results));
    }
} and also added the method l found to the method part of your code, now it's working, perfect and thank you again.

Comment: you might be interested to answer this question maybe? I am pretty sure, it's something very easy for you, thanks in advance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397622/bluej-java-program-returning-a-new-array-containing-the-componentwise-sum-of-i