# BlueJ / Java program returning a new array containing the componentwise sum of its arguments

Tags: java, bluej

The following code returns a new array containing the componentwise sum of its arguments (assuming their length is the same), for example if the input arrays are {0,1,2} and {2,2,3} then the out out will be {2,3,5} and if the input arrays have different numbers of elements, the method should return null.

```
public class Sum
{
    public static double[] sum(double a[], double b[]){

    if (a.length != b.length)
    return null;
    int[] s = new double[a.length];
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    s[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    return s;
    }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        //calling the method to seek if compiles
        double[] results = Sum.sum(new double[] {0,1,2} + {2,2,3});
        //printing the results
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(results));
    }
}
```

As I have mentioned before normally when I run this program code above I supposed to have {2,3,5} as result, but I am getting nothing. In fact I cannot able to compile it in BlueJ, I am keep getting the error message saying: illegal start of expression for this line: double[] results = Sum.sum(new double[] {0,1,2} + {2,2,3});

So I assume I did syntax error, but I am not too sure, how can I get rid of it, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

- The `+` operator is allowed for primitive numeric types only. In this line of code:

  ```
  Sum.sum(new double[] {0,1,2} + {2,2,3});
  ```

  You're trying to apply `+` operator for `double[]` variables, which is not allowed, thus getting the exception. Since the method already accepts 2 arguments `double[]`, then send both `double[]`s by separating them using comma `,`.:

  ```
  Sum.sum(new double[] {0,1,2}, new double[] {2,2,3});
  ```
- This line of code:

  ```
  int[] s = new double[a.length];
  ```

  You cannot initialize an array of primitive type with an array of another primitive type. `int[]` and `double[]` are complete different classes. So, instead change the type declaration for your variable:

  ```
  double[] s = new double[a.length];
  ```

More info:

- [The Java Tutorial. Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)
- [The Java Tutorial. Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)
- [The Java Tutorial. Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
double[] results = sum(new double[] {0,1,2}, new double[] {2,2,3});
```

Comment: now I am getting another error message saying: incompatiple types for line: int[] s = new double[a.length]; , I don't know what's my syntax mistake there.

Comment: Provide an explanation maybe?

Comment: You can't assign array of ints to array of doubles!

Comment: @Arkadiy - This works.  Try it.  Because I've written `new double[]` before the curly braces, there's never any `int[]` here.

Comment: @Acemi - Yes, that's a separate error, that I didn't see when I first read your code.  `s` needs to be `double[]`, not `int[]`.